# IIS URL Rewrite Service1.svc to api

Tags: url-rewriting, biztalk, iis-10

I am trying to use IIS URL Rewrite to rewrite:

`http://localhost/RESTDemo/Service1.svc/Persons` to `http://localhost/RESTDemo/api/Persons`

I have the following configuration in my Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Change 'Service1.svc' to 'api'" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)/RESTDemo/api/(.*)$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/RESTDemo/Service1.svc/{R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

And when I run the **Test pattern** in IIS it seems to be working
[image: Test Pattern in IIS]

But when I test POST to `http://localhost/RESTDemo/api/Persons` I get a 404.0 Not Found from IIS. Then when I try to run the same POST against `http://localhost/RESTDemo/Service1.svc/Persons` it works.

I have tried checking the log under `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1` but can't see anything helpful, even though I have set `logRewrittenUrl="true"` I can only see this in my IIS log:

```
2021-04-20 10:18:48 127.0.0.1 POST /RESTDemo/api/persons - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5+(Java/12.0.1) - 404 0 2 1
```

My questions is..

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Why can't I see the rewritten URL in my log file?

Comment: Start from Mistake 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is a problem with your rewrite rules, you can try the following rewrite rules:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Change 'Service1.svc' to 'api'" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(RESTDemo)/api/(.*)$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="RESTDemo/Service1.svc/{R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Here is my demo:

[image]